# How to assign agents to run specific configuration of a build in parallel?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a build controller C1 and 2 agents Agent1 and Agent2. I am using a parallel template with some custom activities. My build runs for 2 configurations- Release and debug. I want the release to be run explicitly on Agent1 and debug to run on Agent2. But My AgentScope is reserving any of the two agents. I have tried using assign activity, **agentsettings.name="Agent1"** before and after get Build agent, but none have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I found an answer which worked for me. I have set a condition for release configuration and set **agentsettings.name="Agent1"** just before Agent Scope and was successfully running release build on Agent1 and debug build on Agent2.